# I get error in bracket opening a file in Python

Tags: python, file, syntax

I get an error on the [(] bracket opening the file. Please help :)

```
usedbeforefile = open&&(&&'c:\\Documents and Settings\Adam\Desktop\NewProgram\Resources\Alfred\ub4.txt')
```

EDIT: Thank you,  Ashwini Chaudhary

(If you see the '&&' around the bracket that is just me showing where my error was :D)

Comment: Don't use single `\ `, use either `\\ ` or raw strings.

Comment: Please don't just say "I get an error", show us _what_ error, with the whole traceback. If we saw that it was a `SyntaxError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode raw bytes in position 39-40: malformed \N character escape`, any experienced developer could immediately spot the problem, so it wouldn't take 18 minutes for someone to guess the problem (not to mention the possibility of them guessing wrong).

Comment: Also, I assume you're using Python 3.x here (because that line isn't an error in 2.x, although only because you got very lucky). If so, it's usually better to add the python-3.x tag, because a lot of people will assume 2.7 if you don't say otherwise.

Comment: If I get this right, you have an error on the opening paren in `usedbeforefile = open('c:\\Documents and Settings\Adam\Desktop\NewProgram\Resources\Alfred\ub4.txt')` (no ampersands). The '\' escapes may be a problem, but wouldn't cause an error on the first param before the string is processed. The real problem is likely on the line above this one.

Comment: What code is around this? There might be an unpaired "(" further up in your code tht is causing issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
usedbeforefile = open(r'c:\Documents and Settings\Adam\Desktop\NewProgram\Resources\Alfred\ub4.txt')
```

Notice the `r` before the start of the string. That's the way to say: this is a raw string, there's no need to interpret `\` as a special escape character. Another alternative would be to use normal strings and manually escape all `\` characters:

```
usedbeforefile = open('c:\\Documents and Settings\\Adam\\Desktop\\NewProgram\\Resources\\Alfred\\ub4.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use forward slashes on Unix and Windows because Python tries to interpret path portably.

```
usedbeforefile = open('c:/Documents and Settings/Adam/Desktop/NewProgram/Resources/Alfred/ub4.txt')
```